# angularjs: accessibility of services

Tags: angularjs

this is probably a stupid question but here it goes anyway. I know that services are like singleton that's good for storing shared data. However I've been struggling with some concepts - Is it true that when using built-in directives like ng-repeat, do we always have to write "middle-man" methods to access/manipulate the shared objects in services? E.g

we have

```
appModule.service('fruits', function(){
     this.items = ["apples", "bananas"];
});
```

To use `ng-repeat` to access these items, we must first need to write controller method like

```
appModule.controller("fruitsController", function($scope, fruits){
    $scope.getFruits = function(){ return fruits.items;}
});
```

How about using custom directives then? Given that the service can also be injected into a directive, it will have direct access to the service. Is there any pros and cons of either methods?

Comment: I dont fully understand your question. Data shared via a service is used within a custom directive by injecting the service into it, yes. What other method do you want to use?

Comment: What i mean in the first part was, say e.g using ng-repeat, to access data in services, do we always need to create methods in the controller to access the service? And how does this compare to using custom directives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So *I think* you're asking "Why not use custom directives for everything instead of controllers?"...

Well, basically because that would be harder to test. It's sort of like asking "Why separate code at all?".

The purpose of a directive is to provide two way access between your model and your view (the DOM) and handle setting up those interactions.

The purpose of a controller is to encapsulate "business logic" for the app.

Can you mix them both into a directive? Yes. Should you? Probably not.